# how to show error messages in <%= f.error_messages %> with rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in your controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**user_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @company = Company.new(params[:company])
  [@company,@user].each {|ins|
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(ins) unless ins.valid?
    }
  User.transaction do
   @company.save!
   @user.company = @company
   @user.save!   
  end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid          
          render :action => 'new'
end
```

I am not getting error messages through <%= f.error_messages %>
please help!!

Comment: That's no Rails way: overcomplicated and prone to problem => use nested_attributes

Comment: I guess there is a relation between company and user?

Comment: one company has many users, but why cant I get error messages through <%= f.error_messages %> in my view file? what should I do to display error messages??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution:

In your Company model:

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

In your controller:

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(params[:company].merge(:user_attributes => params[:user])
  if @company.save
    #what you want
  else
    @user = @company.user          
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Someday I'll have earned the accept-answer-by-proxy and mark this answer as the accepted one.